# How to stack geography graphs on top of each other?

Tags: matlab

I am drawing a geographic bubble graph (via `geobubble()`) and I want to overlay a geographic line graph (via `geoplot()`) on top of it.

I have tried `hold on`, and it throws out the error `Error using hold (line 42)
Using hold with geobubble is not supported.`

This script generates a geobubble graph.

```
longt = rand(10, 1);
lat = rand(10, 1);
val = 10*rand(10, 1);
gb = geobubble(longt, lat, val);
```

And I want to overlay a line graph on top of it

```
A = [0.1, 0.9];
B = [0.2, 0.8];
geoplot([A(1) B(1)],[A(2) B(2)],'g-*')
```